# How to understand this rather basic complex integral question?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$ is entire in $\mathbb{C} $

then compute

$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} [u(r,\theta)\cos(\theta)-v(r,\theta)\sin(\theta)] d \theta$$

And the hint is to write $z=e^{i \theta}$ and take the contour integral on curve $|z|=1$

The answer is $0$.

But I am confused about how to use the hint without knowing what the actual function is.

My thoughts would be that if $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic then u and v are holomorphic ( is this true?)  and so to are multiples of the holomorphic trig functions, thus everything is holomorphic and by Cauchy theorem it evaluates to zero and this is a closed path.

Also if you were to want to do it the other way as the hint suggested, how?

Comment: If $f = u+iv$ is holomorphic, $u,v$ are known as _harmonic_.  Harmonic functions are very similar to holomorphic ones (they share many properties).  I'm actually unsure of what properties holomorphic functions have that harmonic ones don't (as I don't know a ton about harmonic functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is entire, we have $\int_\gamma f(z)dz $ for any suitable closed curve.

Note that if $\gamma$ is the unit circle, then 
$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{it}) i e^{it} dt$.

Note that $u(e^{it}) \cos t - v(e^{it}) \sin t = \operatorname{im} (f(e^{it}) i e^{it}) $, and so we conclude that
$\int_0^{2 \pi} (u(e^{it}) \cos t - v(e^{it}) \sin t) dt = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, is what I said about f=u+iv being holomorphic implys u and v are true?

Comment: @Quality: I don't understand what you are asking. If $u$ is the real part of $f$, then it cannot be holomorphic (it is harmonic).

Comment: @Quality: The function $\phi(z) = f(z) e^z$ **is** holomorphic, so $\int_\gamma \phi(z) dz = 0$, where $\gamma$ is any suitable closed curve.

Comment: Okay thanks, is that what you are using for the answer above? with f(z)=r((u+iv)

Comment: @Quality: I made a few mistakes, I will fix my answer.